# Getting unwanted solution from Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving the simultaneously equations

$\quad \quad x_7=0$

and

$\quad \quad 6x_4x_5+6x_3x_5x_6+zx_4x_7^2+zx_5x_7^2=0$

with `Solve`. Here, $z$ is an unknown parameter and is independent of the $x_{k}$'s.

```
Solve[
  {x[7] == 0, 6x[4]x[5] + 6x[3]x[5]x[6] + z*x[4]x[7]^2 + z*x[4]x[5]x[7]^2 == 0}, 
  Table[x[k], {k, 1, 7}]]
```

*Mathematica* generates 4 solutions. They are as follows.

1. $\{x[5]\rightarrow 0,\;\;x[7]\rightarrow 0\}$
2. $\{x[6]\rightarrow -\frac{x[4]}{x[3]},\;\;x[7]\rightarrow 0\}$
3. $\{x[3]\rightarrow 0,\;\;x[4]\rightarrow 0,\;\;x[7]\rightarrow 0\}$
4. $\{x[4]\rightarrow 0,\;\;x[5]\rightarrow 0,\;\;x[7]\rightarrow 0\}$

Solution 3 is a result of solution 2 (by looking at the case when $x[3]=0$).

However, if I manually solve the equations, the only valid solutions are the first three. That is, I can substitute $x_{7}=0$ into $6x_4x_5+6x_3x_5x_6+zx_4x_7^2+zx_5x_7^2=0$ to get $6x_4x_5+6x_3x_5x_6=0\;\;\Rightarrow\;\; 6x_{5}(x_{4}+x_{3}x_{6})=0$. Solving this will then give me the first three solutions.

Why is *Mathematica* producing **solution 4** and how do I overcome this problem?

I believe it is related to the unknown parameter $z$.

**Edit:**

In the equations I am solving, I have taken $z$ as an unknown parameter.

If I assign some value (not what I want to do) to $z$, say $z=1$, Mathematica then produces only the first 3 solutions.

Comment: `Solution 3 is a result of solution 2` I do not understand what this means. Each one is an independent solution.  You do not obtain one solution from another? Solution 4th is correct. Try: `vars = {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7]};
eqs = {x[7] == 0, 6 x[4] x[5] + 6 x[3] x[5] x[6] + z*x[4] x[7]^2 + z*x[4] x[5] x[7]^2 == 0};
sol = Solve[eqs, vars]; eqs /. sol[[4]]` and this gives `True`. If you want solution over reals only, add the options `Reals`

Comment: Formally, solution 4 is just as valid as solution 3. I see no problem with the results `Solve` is returning.

Comment: Dear @Nasser, Solution 2 is written in parametric form and is a result of solving $x_{4}+x_{3}x_{6}=0$ (which we get when $x_{7}=0$. This has many solutions because we have one equation but 3 variables. I can choose $x_{4}$ and $x_{3}$ to be free and rewrite $x_{6}$ in terms of these two variables to get $x_{6}=-\frac{x_{4}}{x_{3}}$, where clearly $x_{3}\neq 0$. We also then need to look at the case when $x_{3}=0$ and (if possible) solve $x_{4}+x_{3}x_{6}=0$. When $x_{3}=0$ we then must have $x_{4}=0$ while $x_{6}$ is free. This is basically Solution 3.

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg, The equations are indeed satisfied for Solution 4. But regardless of what $x_{4}$ is the equations will be satisfied (consequence of Solution 1). So, why does Mathematica say $x_{4}=0$ in Solution 4. For argument's sake, suppose I let $z=1$ and then solve the equations in Mathematica. Mathematica then does not display Solution 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eq = {x[7] == 0,  6 x[4] x[5] + 6 x[3] x[5] x[6] + z*x[4] x[7]^2 +  z*x[4] x[5] x[7]^2 == 0}
Solve@FullSimplify[And @@ eq]
(* {{x[4] -> -x[3] x[6], x[7] -> 0}, 
    {x[5] -> 0, x[7] -> 0}}
*)
```

Comment: Dear @belisarius, Thanks. These are the only two solutions that are needed to capture all possible solutions. Really appreciated.